# REG_EXPAND_SZ for 8.3 short names

Tags: windows-registry

I'm trying to solve a `PATH` issue and came across the `REG_SZ` and `REG_EXPAND_SZ` registry types, where REG_EXPAND_SZ must be used when using variables such as %SystemRoot% in the registry key.

My question is, should the REG_EXPAND_SZ type also be used for 8.3 short names such as `C:\Progra~1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> should the REG_EXPAND_SZ type also be used for 8.3 short names such as
>   C:\Progra~1?

Clear no!

> REG_EXPAND_SZ
>
> A null-terminated string that contains unexpanded references to
>   environment variables (for example, "%PATH%"). It will be a Unicode or
>   ANSI string depending on whether you use the Unicode or ANSI
>   functions.

You can look for `"C:\Progra~1"` in Registry (regedit) and will find a lot of `REG_SZ` entries.

Comment: On the other hand, a special type _is not needed_ because the short names (unlike environment variables) are expanded by the filesystem itself.